# How to do type checking with the LLVM C++ API?

Tags: llvm, llvm-c++-api

I've just started learning the LLVM C++ API, and I'm a bit confused about how to do type checking. There's an example my instructor has provided to me about storing a variable in stack memory as follows:

```
llvm::AllocaInst *Alloca;
Alloca = llvm::Builder.CreateAlloca(llvm::IntegerType::get(getGlobalContext(), 32), nullptr, "variable_name");
```

I understand this, but in the next part it talks about type checking before assigning a value to a variable. `To assign a value in a Decaf statement of the type lvalue = rvalue you should get the location of lvalue from the symbol table. You can check the type of rvalue using the following API call:`

```
const llvm::PointerType *ptrTy = rvalue->getType()->getPointerTo();
ptrTy == Alloca->getType()
```

I am utterly confused at why this needs to be done for type checking. I've read the documentation and `getPointerTo` returns a PointerType object. So my first question is, the Type object of Alloca is IntegerType, so why are we creating an object of PointerType? This seems completely out of left field to me.

The second question I have is, why are we then comparing this PointerType object with the Alloca Type object which is an IntegerType object? Is there some sort of == operator overloading? Because I was searching through the documentation and I couldn't find any.

Answer (score 4):

You appear to be following [this tutorial](https://anoopsarkar.github.io/compilers-class/llvm-practice.html). Your question is missing some valuable context which I reproduce below:

> For example the following code uses the LLVM API to create an alloca instruction to store integers (LLVM type i32) on the stack. This storage space is used to store values and to load values from the memory locations on the stack.
>
> ```
> llvm::AllocaInst *Alloca; 
> // unlike CreateEntryBlockAlloca the following will 
> // create the alloca instr at the current insertion point
> // rather than at the start of the block
> Alloca = llvm::Builder.CreateAlloca(llvm::IntegerType::get(getGlobalContext(), 32), nullptr, "variable_name");
> ```
>
> You should then store this pointer into the symbol table for the
>   identifier NAME. You can access the pointer to the type TYPE using
>   `Alloca->getType()` when you want to assign a value to this location.

So `Alloca->getType()` is providing you a PointerType object representing "pointer to `i32`," in particular a pointer to the location in the stack that was allocated for the `i32`. But `rvalue` is an `i32`, not a pointer to `i32`. Even so, we can still use `Alloca->getType()` to compare the type of the `lvalue` (`i32`) to something, namely the type of `rvalue`:

> To assign a value in a Decaf statement of the type `lvalue = rvalue` you
>   should get the location of `lvalue` from the symbol table. You can check
>   the type of `rvalue` using the following API call:
>
> ```
> const llvm::PointerType *ptrTy = rvalue->getType()->getPointerTo();
> ```

We first obtain the type of `rvalue`. We can't compare it directly to the type of `lvalue`, because we only have the type "pointer to type of `lvalue`". So what we have to do is convert the type object obtained from `rvalue` to "pointer to type of `rvalue`"—that is, we convert it from `i32` to a `*i32`.

In other words, how do we check that `rvalue` has type `i32` if all we have to compare it to is the type `*i32`? The answer is, we just promote `rvalue`'s type to a pointer type, i.e. take its `i32` and make it a pointer `*i32`.

At this point `ptrTy` contains the type "pointer to type of `rvalue`", while we also know that `Alloca->getType()` gives us the type "pointer to type of `lvalue`." In order to assign the `rvalue` to `lvalue`, we check that these two types coincide:

> And check that the type of the Alloca location for lvalue has the same
>   type:
>
> ```
> ptrTy == Alloca->getType()
> ```

The expression above is the conditional; it is true if the types are the same and false otherwise. Assuming it's true, you assign the values like so:

> ```
> llvm::Value *val = Builder.CreateStore(rvalue, Alloca)
> ```

Comment: The point I'm really confused about is `const llvm::PointerType *ptrTy = rvalue->getType()->getPointerTo();`. I've been reading the documentation and `getPointerTo` creates a PointerType object, why do we need to do this? Why not just use `getType()` which returns the Type object itself? Why get the Type object of rvalue, then create a PointerType object out of it?

Also in the equality check, how does checking if two pointers are equal let us know the types are equal? These are two different objects the pointers are pointing to, so why are we comparing them?

Comment: If you ask alloca for enough space for a 48-bit integer, alloca returns a pointer to a 48-bit integer. Naturally alloca's return value has a pointer type.

Comment: @girbic I updated my answer to clarify why we are getting the pointer type of rvalue instead of just the type of rvalue. In short, it's because we have the pointer type of the type of lvalue, namely `*i32`, not lvalue's type `i32`.